# Salesforce1: Fill lookup value in action from page

Tags: salesforce1-app, lookup

I have custom objects "Department" and "Visit in Department". In "Visit in Department" there is a custom lookup field "Visited department". On "Department" page I added an action "Log a visit".

On web when I click "Log a visit" on Department's page (let say NYC Office) I see "Create visit in department" page and "Visited department" field contains the right Department (i.e. NYC Office).

Unfortunatelly when I try this on mobile (Salesforce1) my "Department" field doesn't contain any value.

It should work like a "log a call" action on leads page and "log a call" works correctly OOTB on Salesforce1.

Comment: Is the same custom field/action enabled for logging in Activities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.

The problem occured because I created "Log a visit" as a global action. When I created it as an action on "Department" settings page it works as expected even in Salesforce1.